# Convert int to truncated decimal

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I convert `51501319` to `51.5`? (needs to round to `.5`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Round( 51501319 / 1000000.000, 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST( CAST(51501319 AS decimal(10,1)) / 1000000  AS decimal(10,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND( (1.0*5150319)/100000, 1)
```

This will get 51.5  but is this really what you want?  What should it do with 5159999?  Do you want 51.5 or 51.6, or 52.0?